# Spring Batch Process hanging after the writer completes

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am at a loss how to debug this issue, so not even sure which code snippets to put up. Here is the basic setup:

I have to read from a REST API and write to a SOAP API. As far as I can tell the reading and writing are working without any issue. I have 3 sets of reads with 3 matching sets of writes that can happen in parallel so I have built them using the FlowBuilder like so:

```
final Flow firstFlow = new FlowBuilder<Flow>("firstFlow").from(Step1).end();
final Flow secondFlow = new FlowBuilder<Flow>("secondFlow").from(Step2).end();
final Flow thirdFlow = new FlowBuilder<Flow>("thirdFlow").from(Step3).end();

Flow mdmFlow = builder2.split(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor()).add(firstFlow, secondFlow, thirdFlow).build();
FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow> builder2 = new FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow>("attribsAndItemsFlow");
```

Then I build it like so:

```
return jobs.get("feedControlJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(listener)
                .preventRestart()
                .start(mdmFlow)
                .end()
                .build();
```

In the listener I have:

```
public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
    log.info("Starting Batch Job...");
}
```

Which does put the line in the log, so I know the listener is being loaded properly. I also have:

```
@Override
public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
    log.info("Batch job finished, saving state.");
    // some stuf to write files here
}
```

That log.info never runs so I am sure it is not getting there. However, the last line of my writer is:

```
log.debug("Finished writes.");
```

That does write to the log for all three flows. When I try walking through with the debugger I quickly end up in sections of code that STS does not have the source for.

Best I can tell is that some place between the end of the last writer exit, and before the After Job event, something is wrong. I get no errors in the console.

I ran it with log level set to debug, here is the output starting with my last line of code:

```
2016-08-30 16:46:37.046 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] com.dcsg.writeobject.MdmItemWriterClass  : Finished writes.
2016-08-30 16:46:37.046 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.b.c.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet   : Inputs not busy, ended: true
2016-08-30 16:46:37.046 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep  : Applying contribution: [StepContribution: read=20, written=20, filtered=0, readSkips=0, writeSkips=0, processSkips=0, exitStatus=EXECUTING]
2016-08-30 16:46:37.046 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager     : Participating in existing transaction
2016-08-30 16:46:37.047 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL update
2016-08-30 16:46:37.047 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [UPDATE BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT SET SHORT_CONTEXT = ?, SERIALIZED_CONTEXT = ? WHERE STEP_EXECUTION_ID = ?]
2016-08-30 16:46:37.048 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : SQL update affected 1 rows
2016-08-30 16:46:37.049 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep  : Saving step execution before commit: StepExecution: id=0, version=1, name=GG Step, status=STARTED, exitStatus=EXECUTING, readCount=20, filterCount=0, writeCount=20 readSkipCount=0, writeSkipCount=0, processSkipCount=0, commitCount=1, rollbackCount=0, exitDescription=
2016-08-30 16:46:37.049 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager     : Participating in existing transaction
2016-08-30 16:46:37.049 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL update
2016-08-30 16:46:37.049 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [UPDATE BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION set START_TIME = ?, END_TIME = ?, STATUS = ?, COMMIT_COUNT = ?, READ_COUNT = ?, FILTER_COUNT = ?, WRITE_COUNT = ?, EXIT_CODE = ?, EXIT_MESSAGE = ?, VERSION = ?, READ_SKIP_COUNT = ?, PROCESS_SKIP_COUNT = ?, WRITE_SKIP_COUNT = ?, ROLLBACK_COUNT = ?, LAST_UPDATED = ? where STEP_EXECUTION_ID = ? and VERSION = ?]
2016-08-30 16:46:37.050 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : SQL update affected 1 rows
2016-08-30 16:46:37.050 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL query
2016-08-30 16:46:37.050 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT VERSION FROM BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION WHERE JOB_EXECUTION_ID=?]
2016-08-30 16:46:37.051 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager     : Initiating transaction commit
2016-08-30 16:46:37.051 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager     : Committing JDBC transaction on Connection [org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection@557528a5]
2016-08-30 16:46:37.051 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager     : Releasing JDBC Connection [org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection@557528a5] after transaction
2016-08-30 16:46:37.052 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils      : Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
2016-08-30 16:46:37.052 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate  : Repeat is complete according to policy and result value.
2016-08-30 16:46:37.052 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Step execution success: id=0
2016-08-30 16:46:37.052 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager     : Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.updateExecutionContext]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
2016-08-30 16:46:37.052 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.j.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource  : Creating new JDBC Driver Connection to [jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb]
2016-08-30 16:46:37.052 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager     : Acquired Connection [org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection@5e762da3] for JDBC transaction
2016-08-30 16:46:37.052 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager     : Switching JDBC Connection [org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection@5e762da3] to manual commit
2016-08-30 16:46:37.053 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL update
2016-08-30 16:46:37.053 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [UPDATE BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT SET SHORT_CONTEXT = ?, SERIALIZED_CONTEXT = ? WHERE STEP_EXECUTION_ID = ?]
2016-08-30 16:46:37.054 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : SQL update affected 1 rows
2016-08-30 16:46:37.054 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager     : Initiating transaction commit
2016-08-30 16:46:37.054 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager     : Committing JDBC transaction on Connection [org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection@5e762da3]
2016-08-30 16:46:37.054 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager     : Releasing JDBC Connection [org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection@5e762da3] after transaction
2016-08-30 16:46:37.054 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils      : Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
2016-08-30 16:46:37.054 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager     : Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.update]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
2016-08-30 16:46:37.054 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.j.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource  : Creating new JDBC Driver Connection to [jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb]
2016-08-30 16:46:37.054 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager     : Acquired Connection [org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection@5a915472] for JDBC transaction
2016-08-30 16:46:37.055 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager     : Switching JDBC Connection [org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection@5a915472] to manual commit
2016-08-30 16:46:37.055 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL update
2016-08-30 16:46:37.055 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [UPDATE BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION set START_TIME = ?, END_TIME = ?, STATUS = ?, COMMIT_COUNT = ?, READ_COUNT = ?, FILTER_COUNT = ?, WRITE_COUNT = ?, EXIT_CODE = ?, EXIT_MESSAGE = ?, VERSION = ?, READ_SKIP_COUNT = ?, PROCESS_SKIP_COUNT = ?, WRITE_SKIP_COUNT = ?, ROLLBACK_COUNT = ?, LAST_UPDATED = ? where STEP_EXECUTION_ID = ? and VERSION = ?]
2016-08-30 16:46:37.056 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : SQL update affected 1 rows
2016-08-30 16:46:37.056 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL query
2016-08-30 16:46:37.056 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT VERSION FROM BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION WHERE JOB_EXECUTION_ID=?]
2016-08-30 16:46:37.056 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager     : Initiating transaction commit
2016-08-30 16:46:37.057 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager     : Committing JDBC transaction on Connection [org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection@5a915472]
2016-08-30 16:46:37.057 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager     : Releasing JDBC Connection [org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection@5a915472] after transaction
2016-08-30 16:46:37.057 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils      : Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
2016-08-30 16:46:37.057 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Step execution complete: StepExecution: id=0, version=3, name=GG Step, status=COMPLETED, exitStatus=COMPLETED, readCount=20, filterCount=0, writeCount=20 readSkipCount=0, writeSkipCount=0, processSkipCount=0, commitCount=1, rollbackCount=0
2016-08-30 16:46:37.057 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager     : Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.updateExecutionContext]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
2016-08-30 16:46:37.057 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.j.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource  : Creating new JDBC Driver Connection to [jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb]
2016-08-30 16:46:37.057 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager     : Acquired Connection [org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection@5802f2e9] for JDBC transaction
2016-08-30 16:46:37.057 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager     : Switching JDBC Connection [org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection@5802f2e9] to manual commit
2016-08-30 16:46:37.058 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL update
2016-08-30 16:46:37.058 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [UPDATE BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT SET SHORT_CONTEXT = ?, SERIALIZED_CONTEXT = ? WHERE JOB_EXECUTION_ID = ?]
2016-08-30 16:46:37.058 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : SQL update affected 1 rows
2016-08-30 16:46:37.059 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager     : Initiating transaction commit
2016-08-30 16:46:37.059 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager     : Committing JDBC transaction on Connection [org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection@5802f2e9]
2016-08-30 16:46:37.059 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager     : Releasing JDBC Connection [org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection@5802f2e9] after transaction
2016-08-30 16:46:37.059 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils      : Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
2016-08-30 16:46:37.059 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.b.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow   : Completed state=thirdFlow.GG Step with status=COMPLETED
2016-08-30 16:46:37.059 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.b.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow   : Handling state=thirdFlow.COMPLETED
2016-08-30 16:46:37.059 DEBUG 11260 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.b.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow   : Completed state=thirdFlow.COMPLETED with status=COMPLETED
```

After that, it just hangs indefinitely.

EDIT: A Thread Dump was requested, so here is one from while it is hanging:

```
2016-09-01 13:42:00
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.66-b18 mixed mode):

"SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1" #16 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000211c2000 nid=0x157c runnable [0x000000001eb0d000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000006c1eba630> (a java.lang.Object)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000006c1ebb978> (a sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000006c1ebb950> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000006c1ef2178> (a sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000006c1ef2178> (a sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpResponse.getRawStatusCode(SimpleClientHttpResponse.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpResponse.getStatusCode(AbstractClientHttpResponse.java:33)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.getHttpStatusCode(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.hasError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:629)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:597)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:557)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:475)
    at com.dcsg.mdm.MdmItemItemReaderClass.getResultSetId(MdmItemItemReaderClass.java:173)
    at com.dcsg.mdm.MdmItemItemReaderClass.init(MdmItemItemReaderClass.java:84)
    at com.dcsg.mdm.MdmItemItemReaderClass.read(MdmItemItemReaderClass.java:107)
    at com.dcsg.mdm.MdmItemItemReaderClass.read(MdmItemItemReaderClass.java:1)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:91)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.read(SimpleChunkProvider.java:157)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:116)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.provide(SimpleChunkProvider.java:110)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:69)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:81)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:200)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.SplitState$1.call(SplitState.java:93)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.SplitState$1.call(SplitState.java:90)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

"RMI TCP Accept-0" #13 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001e36f800 nid=0xbf8 runnable [0x000000001f8df000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.accept0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000006c0046480> (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(Unknown Source)
    at sun.management.jmxremote.LocalRMIServerSocketFactory$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

"RMI TCP Accept-26293" #12 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001e381000 nid=0x15e0 runnable [0x000000001f7ae000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.accept0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000006c00469e0> (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

"RMI TCP Accept-0" #11 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001e388800 nid=0x2ba4 runnable [0x000000001ed3e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.accept0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000006c0046e70> (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

"Service Thread" #9 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001e018000 nid=0x1e24 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C1 CompilerThread2" #8 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001df94800 nid=0x28b0 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" #7 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001df92800 nid=0x2150 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" #6 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001c89d000 nid=0x2d8c waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Attach Listener" #5 daemon prio=5 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001c89b800 nid=0x2de4 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001c898800 nid=0x2d18 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=1 tid=0x000000001c834000 nid=0x2988 in Object.wait() [0x000000001da1f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000006c0089980> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000006c0089980> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Unknown Source)

"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001c832000 nid=0x2e58 in Object.wait() [0x000000001d90f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000006c00899c0> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000006c00899c0> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002baa000 nid=0x2a64 waiting on condition [0x0000000002f7d000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000006c1fc8ea0> (a java.util.concurrent.FutureTask)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.awaitDone(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.SplitState.handle(SplitState.java:113)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:134)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:306)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.execute(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:216)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:233)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:125)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.run(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:119)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:800)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:784)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:771)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174)
    at com.dcsg.mdm.MdmAttributeControlApplication.main(MdmAttributeControlApplication.java:28)

"VM Thread" os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001c82c800 nid=0x2d14 runnable 

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002bbe800 nid=0x2bd0 runnable 

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002bc0000 nid=0x272c runnable 

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002bc2000 nid=0x1ca8 runnable 

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002bc5800 nid=0x2b3c runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001e371000 nid=0x2a00 waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 237
```

Comment: Normally, I build flows like 'new FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow>("name")
    .start(step1).build()'. Try this instead of using 'from' and 'end'. Probably it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have change my code as you suggested,  but the bug still happens.

Comment: What is about the other two threads (firstflow, secondflow)? Do they reach state completed as well? Have you tried to implement your job just with a normal readers and writers (no Rest and Soap - just for testing)?

Comment: Yes all flows complete and write to the log at that same line. Two fo the flows complete way ahead of the third.

Comment: I have not written non-rest/soap reader/writer in this specific program, but if I make them pretty much do nothing, the bug does not seem to occur.

Comment: Are you using the same reader and writer instances? could there be a kind of lock problem? Have you tried making a threaddump when the batch finally hangs?

Comment: What I did try this AM was change it to three sequential flows using ".next()" and the bug does not occur when I do that.  This will be slow for production, I really need them to run in parallel. But it seemed like a good test at least.

Comment: Each flow has three beans, so should not be the same instance, even though the underlying class type is the same.

Comment: Will get a thread dump, did not think of that.

Comment: Added thread dump to OP.

Comment: As you can see, the thread "SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1" ist still reading from. the read method at "com.dcsg.mdm.MdmItemItemReaderClass.read()" has to return null, after the last item is read. But it seems as this is never happening. Your reader is still reading. And as long as  this method does not return null, it continues to read.

Comment: That seems odd, since the first line of the reader is: 

`public SkuResponseClass read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {  
  log.debug(this.prefix + ": Begining Read Pass: "+ pageIndex);`

If it was reading over and over I should see that debug line in the logs over and over, right?

Comment: Well, the thread dump doesn't lie :-) the thread sits there and waits.

Comment: Well log.debug should not be lying either :-) I do return null when it is done reading, but I will comb through it again and see if there is condition that I did not account for and something other than null is getting returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that at least in some cases, RestTemplate.exchange() can get into a state where it never returns. When this happens, the ItemReader also never returns, and no errors are reported. The Batch process gets to the end, and sees one (or more) ItemReader process is still unfinished, and waits indefinitely for that reader to return. I have even let it sit overnight, it never gives up waiting.

I resolved this by adding a time out to the RestTemplate call. To set the timeout you need to create a ClientHttpRequest like so:

```
private ClientHttpRequestFactory getClientHttpRequestFactory() {
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        clientHttpRequestFactory.setConnectTimeout(this.timeout);
        return clientHttpRequestFactory;
    }
```

Then when you create the RestTemplage, you do it like so:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(getClientHttpRequestFactory());
```

I had assumed that the RestTemplate had some default timeout, but that does not appear to be the case.

I was finally able to track this down thanks to Hansjoerg's suggestion above to study the thread dump.